# Does NGXS supports undo like redux-undo

Tags: redux, ngxs, angular-redux

I'm looking into adding a state management to my web app.
I'm using Angular 6.
I've seen this library, which looks promising:
https://github.com/angular-redux/store

But I'm agreeing with the writer of NGXS that decorators are probably the right way.
I also want to add undo-redo to the state management and it seems that angular-redux has this with redux-undo:
https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo

Is there an equivalent to this in NGXS? (I don't need something that fancy)

Do I need to manually to write it?

Comment: It looks like you could implement a plugin to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Right now NGXS dont have any support for "undo" functionality.

Also, if you can explain why you need undo functionality, i try to help with possible way.

Check this issue : https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/269